# React / Redux: focus input field in componentWillReceiveProps not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have two components. When in component A somebody clicks a button, I want to focus an input field in component B.

I am using Redux, and in my Redux store I save `dataInputFocus`, and whenever this is set true, I re-render my component & want to focus the input field.
This does not work however: `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` is called  and it also goes into the `if` (I tried some `console.logs`), but `this.myInp.focus();` is just not working.

```
// Import React
import React from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {addData, setInputFocus} from '../actions/index'

// Create Search component class
class Data extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: ""};

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
      if(nextProps.applicationState.dataInputFocus) {
          this.myInp.focus();
      }

  }

  onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({value: "" });
    this.props.addData(this.state.value, this.props.preferences.type);
  }
  handleInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
          <input
            placeholder="data"
            className="myInput"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            ref={(ip) => this.myInp = ip}
          />

            <button>Add</button>



            <span>{this.props.applicationState.dataInputFocus? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'}</span>
            {/*  I added this line in order to test whether this actually works, but also so that my component re-renders, since I would not actually use dataInputFocus anywhere other than in the conditional */}
        </form>

        <button onClick={() => {this.myInp.focus()}}>Focus Input</button>  {/* this however does(!) work */}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

// Export Search
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    data: state.data,
    preferences: state.preferences,
    applicationState: state.applicationState
  };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    addData: addData
  }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Data);
```

This is the component which receives the props and contains the input field to be focused. Since it goes into `componentWillReceiveProps` and since I also checked that the props is actually changing and it goes into the `if` conditional, I assume that there is something wrong with this component, not my reducer / redux or the other component which contains the button and dispatches the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [componentDidUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated, instead of componentWillReceiveProps (that is called before re-render occurs)

Answer (score 0):

I have a reason that this line( `this.myInp.focus();`) is not working because the component is rendered after componentWillReceiveProps and it is not able to find `ref={(ip) => this.myInp = ip}` the reference of the input box... so see my idea below..

```
//create a state variable or global variable
var isFocus= false
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

// change value
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
      if(nextProps.applicationState.dataInputFocus) {
          isFocus= true
      }
  } 

//after getting reference from render function make it focus.. 


    componentDidMount()
     {
       if(isFocus)
        this.myInp.focus(); 
     }
```

Cheers :)

Comment: thanks. but why could I not just do : `componentDidMount()
   {
     if(this.props.applicationState.dataInputFocus)
      this.myInp.focus();
   }` ?

Comment: yeah you can do that also and you can setstate also.. :)

Comment: I just tried it out, but it does not work, the input field does not focus.

Comment: no. but after the initial starting of my application, the componentDidMount is never called again.

Comment: I don't know the exact config of your application, so no problem we will call   that function in the render() . See the edits